# Display property issue

Tags: html, css, display

I want the two div containers inside the `.firstcontainer` div to appear side by side so I gave them the `display: inline-block`, but that doesn't seem to work.

```css
.firstcontainer {
  display: block;
}

.imagecontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.SeasonCounterContainer {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="centralcontainer">
  <div class="firstcontainer">
    <div class="imagecontainer">
      <img src="http://subs-40ea.kxcdn.com/posters/better-call-saul.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="SeasonCounterContainer">
      <p>46 min | Crime, Drama</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I've already tried different solutions but none worked for me.

Comment: It's `type="text/css"` not `type="text\css"`. And with HTML5 you don't even need the type.

Comment: Is `body` tag optional?

Comment: thanks for correcting.I tried without body it is properly etching tags on the page

Comment: What do you mean as "side by side"?

Comment: They actually are side-by-side, so what's the problem?

Comment: You could always just `float` them.

Comment: float works indeed.But i want to know why it doesn't work for inline-block

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `width` setting on those inline-blocks to get them side by side, since the default width of inline-blocks is the width of their contents, up to 100% of the parent. Also the image width needs to be restricted to not become more than the width of its container.

```css
.firstcontainer {
  display: block;
}

.imagecontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 200px;
}

.imagecontainer img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.SeasonCounterContainer {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="centralcontainer">
  <div class="firstcontainer">
    <div class="imagecontainer">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400/fa0">
    </div>

    <div class="SeasonCounterContainer">
      <p>46 min | Crime, Drama</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why is that text being displayed at the end?

Comment: Because inine-blocks are aligned across their *baseline*, which is the last text line or - if there is no text - the lower border. You can use `vertical-align: top` or `...middle` or  `...bottom` to change that (on both)